# Mapping a hostname to an IP address on Android

Tags: android, hostname

I know that I have to edit the /system/etc/hosts to map an IP address to a host name, but it seems that I can't edit the file. Is it because my android phone is not rooted?

Kindly advise. Thanks.

Comment: Please explain the reason why you need to map a host name to an ip in the device. If you develop an app use read DNS resolution or simply access the ip address directly.

Comment: @rurouni there are thousand reasons to do this. I need to connect to a service in my local environment that will be tested before deploy to the production server and don't want to use an IP.

Answer (score 18):

You can use the following guide and application to setup rules for specific domains.

- Download ([Daedalus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.itxtech.daedalus)) and open the application.
- Click on the menu then click “Servers”

[image: menu]

- Click the add button and add the two google servers “8.8.8.8” and “8.8.4.4”, You can substitute these for your preferred DNS provider as well.

[image: dns settings]

- Activate these dns servers in the menu by clicking on “Settings”
- Then select Google and Google 2 from the settings. Also activate Advance settings and select the two following options in the image below

[image: settings]

- Back to the menu now, Click on “Rules”.
- Add a new rule for each development mode, Live, staging, dev. Filename is not crucial, just make something up.
- Hit sync rule before leaving to make sure the file is downloaded.

  [image: rules]
- Tap and activate the mode you wish to be in, You can activate more than one at a time so be careful as this will override one or the other.
- In the menu go to home, and hit the “Activate” button.

[image: activate]

Source: https://silocitylabs.com/post/2018/03/02/changing-dns-settings-for-android-development/

Comment: why do these apps always want you to download rule files instead of allowing to just create entries?

Comment: Why the "See the world outside" above "DEACTIVATE" ? Does that mean while developing you'll get out of internet? What if the Application also need some internet resources and not only from Web Server on LAN.

Answer (score -4):

Try to remount using adb and edit the file

Answer (score -6):

Why do you need to edit the hosts file?

You can simply add your host to a local DNS (e.g. the DNS announced by a local DHCP-Server in your Wifi-Network) or even in the real global DNS.

Comment: how can i exactly do this ? I have these items in my wifi-network config: `1-DHCP Server Configuration`, `2-Permanent Host Configuration`, `3-DHCP Leased Hosts`, `4-IP Pass Through Configuration` .

Comment: This has nothing to do with the settings on the device. You would just enter the name in your DNS configuration (assuming you have set up your own DNS server) and announce that service via DHCP to the device (most routers allow you to set custom DNS). Or if you are using a DNS service provider register a hostname with your devices IP (I would suggest you use a fixed address for this to work stable).

Comment: And how do you think we will modify the Google dns Server to add our local IP ?

Comment: @MagnoC not by editing stuff on your phone. You will need to use a domain name registrar if you want to edit google dns server so everyone can get the domain name resolution.